# Can you link to a good MySQL dumper PHP script?

Tags: mysql, php

I need to migrate a website to another host. I have only FTP server access and MySQL name+pass (the MySQL server's IP I was provided is 127.0.0.1, and there's neither PhpMyAdmin nor SSHell to use). A web app run there can access the DB using credentials I know and localhost server. So I'd need a PHP script, that will correctly dump all the available databases of the MySQL server so that they can be imported on the new server. Can you recommend a good one?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm my first mind was:

```
<?php
$command = 'mysqldump -h hostname -u user -p password db_name > dumped_db.db';
system($command);
?>
```

Anyway here is a class:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/16861.html

And ready tool (Bigdump is really cool!):

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php

Answer (score 0):

[Mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is what you are looking for, though its written in perl (all nix's have perl)

Comment: I'll try if I find no other solution, but that's a strictly sandboxed shared PHP hosting (the ISP provides only static, PHP and ASP tariffs), it may not have Perl enabled (but may have, worth a try).